# Why can I increment a char array position inside a function and not in main

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, increment

What's the difference between this function parameter stringLength(char string[]) to stringLength(char *string), shouldn't the first one not allow the incrementation(string = string +1) that has a comment on the code below?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int stringLength(char string[]) {
    int length = 0;
    while(*string) {
        string = string + 1; // I can do it here
        length++;
    }
    return length;
}

int main(void){
    char s[] = "HOUSE";
    s = s + 1;  // I can not do it here
    printf("%s\n", s);
    printf("%d\n", stringLength(s));
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's because `s` is an **array** in `main`, but when you pass it as a parameter in `stringLength` it decays into a **pointer**.

It means that `string` is not an array, it is a pointer, which contains the *address* of `s`. The compiler changes it without telling you, so it is equivalent to write the function as:

```
int stringLength(char *string);
```

There's a [page](http://c-faq.com/~scs/cgi-bin/faqcat.cgi?sec=aryptr) that talks about C arrays and pointers in the C-Faq

From there, I recommend you to read questions:

- [6.6](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryparmasgn.html) Why you can modify `string` in `stringLength`
- [6.7](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/arraylval.html) Why you can't modify `s` in `main`
- [6.2](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptr2.html) I heard `char a[]` was identical to `char *a`
- [6.3](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrequiv.html) what is meant by the *``equivalence of pointers and arrays''* in C?
- [6.4](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrparam.html) why are array and pointer declarations interchangeable as function formal parameters?

Comment: @H2CO3 - I just looked at the link, and I'm convinced. But yes, your endorsement clinches the deal J . Gets my vote. I was getting hung up on the "decays" word... I used not to care about these things, then I cared too much. Now I am not sure if I'm still uncertain or not.